# GeoServer WPS request "Failed to retrieve value for input geom"

Tags: geoserver, wfs, buffer, wps, request

I am trying to do a buffer with WPS request builder of GeoServer.
I copied the URL of the gml3 output in GeoServer:

[image]

and I pasted it as the input URL

[image]

I ran the process and I received the following error:

> JTS:bufferBufferReturns a polygonal geometry representing the input geometry enlarged by a given distance around its exterior.Failed to retrieve value for input geom

the request is like this:
[image]

What can I do to fix it? Is the way I gave the URL as input of the process correct?

Should I change the name of the geom column of the input data?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a [bug](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-9441).

In the log file I see:

```
2019-12-20 17:55:41,351 WARN [org.geoserver.wps.executor] - Failed to retrieve value for input geom
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Decoded result is not a org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry, got a: org.geotools.gml3.bindings.DelayedSchemaFeatureCollection
        at org.geoserver.wps.executor.RemoteRequestInputProvider.getValueInternal(RemoteRequestInputProvider.java:217)
        at org.geoserver.wps.executor.AbstractInputProvider.getValue(AbstractInputProvider.java:100)
        at org.geoserver.wps.executor.LazyInputMap.parseInputs(LazyInputMap.java:89)
        at org.geoserver.wps.executor.LazyInputMap.get(LazyInputMap.java:49)
        at org.geotools.process.factory.AnnotationDrivenProcessFactory$InvokeMethodProcess.buildProcessArguments(AnnotationDrivenProcessFactory.java:740)
        at org.geotools.process.factory.AnnotationDrivenProcessFactory$InvokeMethodProcess.execute(AnnotationDrivenProcessFactory.java:620)
        at org.geoserver.wps.executor.ProcessStartupFilter$ProcessStartupWrapper.execute(ProcessStartupFilter.java:50)
        at org.geoserver.wps.executor.DefaultProcessManager$ProcessCallable.call(DefaultProcessManager.java:227)
        at org.geoserver.wps.executor.DefaultProcessManager$ProcessCallable.call(DefaultProcessManager.java:195)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-12-20 17:55:41,351 ERROR [org.geoserver.wps.executor] - Process execution failed
org.geoserver.wps.WPSException: Failed to retrieve value for input geom
        at org.geoserver.wps.executor.RemoteRequestInputProvider.getValueInternal(RemoteRequestInputProvider.java:229)
        at org.geoserver.wps.executor.AbstractInputProvider.getValue(AbstractInputProvider.java:100)
        at org.geoserver.wps.executor.LazyInputMap.parseInputs(LazyInputMap.java:89)
        at org.geoserver.wps.executor.LazyInputMap.get(LazyInputMap.java:49)
        at org.geotools.process.factory.AnnotationDrivenProcessFactory$InvokeMethodProcess.buildProcessArguments(AnnotationDrivenProcessFactory.java:740)
        at org.geotools.process.factory.AnnotationDrivenProcessFactory$InvokeMethodProcess.execute(AnnotationDrivenProcessFactory.java:620)
        at org.geoserver.wps.executor.ProcessStartupFilter$ProcessStartupWrapper.execute(ProcessStartupFilter.java:50)
        at org.geoserver.wps.executor.DefaultProcessManager$ProcessCallable.call(DefaultProcessManager.java:227)
        at org.geoserver.wps.executor.DefaultProcessManager$ProcessCallable.call(DefaultProcessManager.java:195)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Oddly, it also fails for a JSON payload:

```
2019-12-20 17:56:16,569 WARN [org.geoserver.wps.executor] - Failed to retrieve value for input geom
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.geotools.geojson.feature.FeatureCollectionHandler.<init>(org.locationtech.jts.geom.GeometryFactory)
        at org.geotools.geojson.DelegatingHandler.createDelegate(DelegatingHandler.java:125)
        at org.geotools.geojson.geom.GeometryHandler.primitive(GeometryHandler.java:58)
        at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.geotools.geojson.GeoJSONUtil.parse(GeoJSONUtil.java:260)
        at org.geotools.geojson.geom.GeometryJSON.parse(GeometryJSON.java:623)
        at org.geotools.geojson.geom.GeometryJSON.read(GeometryJSON.java:181)
        at org.geotools.geojson.geom.GeometryJSON.read(GeometryJSON.java:193)
        at org.geoserver.wps.ppio.GeoJSONPPIO$Geometries.decode(GeoJSONPPIO.java:79)
        at org.geoserver.wps.executor.RemoteRequestInputProvider.getValueInternal(RemoteRequestInputProvider.java:207)
        at org.geoserver.wps.executor.AbstractInputProvider.getValue(AbstractInputProvider.java:100)
        at org.geoserver.wps.executor.LazyInputMap.parseInputs(LazyInputMap.java:89)
        at org.geoserver.wps.executor.LazyInputMap.get(LazyInputMap.java:49)
        at org.geotools.process.factory.AnnotationDrivenProcessFactory$InvokeMethodProcess.buildProcessArguments(AnnotationDrivenProcessFactory.java:740)
        at org.geotools.process.factory.AnnotationDrivenProcessFactory$InvokeMethodProcess.execute(AnnotationDrivenProcessFactory.java:620)
        at org.geoserver.wps.executor.ProcessStartupFilter$ProcessStartupWrapper.execute(ProcessStartupFilter.java:50)
        at org.geoserver.wps.executor.DefaultProcessManager$ProcessCallable.call(DefaultProcessManager.java:227)
        at org.geoserver.wps.executor.DefaultProcessManager$ProcessCallable.call(DefaultProcessManager.java:195)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.geotools.geojson.feature.FeatureCollectionHandler.<init>(org.locationtech.jts.geom.GeometryFactory)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
        at org.geotools.geojson.DelegatingHandler.createDelegate(DelegatingHandler.java:119)
        ... 21 more
```

Comment: I am using version : 2.15.0.

yes, I tried with many functions and many data types. Never worked unless when I used GeoJSON as Text input.  I have no idea what is wrong.
maybe it is the way I am feeding the input or maybe the installation of WPS has problem.
I have no idea.

Comment: As I say, I think it's a bug. Nothing to do with you or your install.